# STM32 I2C HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady() infinite loop problem

Tags: stm32, i2c, stm32h743

I use an STM32H743ZIT6 to communicate with an LMP92066 temperature sensor.

When I call `HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady()` method to find Slave Address, it goes into an infinite while loop in the method and does not return anything.

`HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady()` method includes the following loop. This loop is infinite because `tmp1` and `tmp2` are always `RESET`.

```c
while ((tmp1 == RESET) && (tmp2 == RESET))
      {
        if (Timeout != HAL_MAX_DELAY)
        {
          if (((HAL_GetTick() - tickstart) > Timeout) || (Timeout == 0U))
          {
            /* Update I2C state */
            hi2c->State = HAL_I2C_STATE_READY;

            /* Update I2C error code */
            hi2c->ErrorCode |= HAL_I2C_ERROR_TIMEOUT;

            /* Process Unlocked */
            __HAL_UNLOCK(hi2c);

            return HAL_ERROR;
          }
        }

        tmp1 = __HAL_I2C_GET_FLAG(hi2c, I2C_FLAG_STOPF);
        tmp2 = __HAL_I2C_GET_FLAG(hi2c, I2C_FLAG_AF);
      }
```

I have tried using I2C2, I2C3, I2C4 instead of I2C1 and it does not work.

I have used `__HAL_RCC_I2C1_CLK_ENABLE();` before calling method but it does not work too.

Comment: Have you got the clock phase and polarity correct? There are only 4 possible combinations to try, might as well try them all.

Comment: Also note that you have to shift the device address left one bit. And note that it does not have to be an infinite loop, you can specify a timeout in milliseconds.

Comment: It seems like the loop waits for either Arbitration loss flag or Stop bit flag to declare the bus "available". I guess a way out of the loop is to have a stop bit flag set. But if your I2C is interrupt-driven (not blocking), it may require small adjustments in how and where interrupts are triggered and flags are cleared.